# Wonderputt, custom engine or reused one

Tags: actionscript-3

like many others i guess, i came across the wonderful game of "wonderputt" (http://www.dampgnat.com/wonderputt)

I was wondering if anyone knows how it was produced.
Did they use an engine like box2d or rolled their own?
Did they use the Stage3D Feature or pre-render the grafix?

Any Infos greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of info on how **Wonderputt** was developed in the own author's [Development Diary](http://www.dampgnat.com/wonderputtwip). Apparently they used a custom framework built for another of their games, [Adverputt](http://www.adverputt.com/).

More useful info can be found in these interviews:

http://truepcgaming.com/2011/09/12/delightfully-addicting-mini-golf-wonderputt-interview/

http://mochiland.com/articles/flash-game-friday-winner-wonderputt

Hope this helps!